# Retornar todos os resultados de uma consulta com mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, agendamento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá,

Estou tentando implementar um sistema de agendamento de quadras onde o usuário escolhe a data e o local de sua preferência. Após isso, ele escolherá os horários de acordo com a disponibilidade e preciso bloquear agendamentos de horários que estejam indisponíveis. Tentei procurar no banco de dados e criar um array de todos os horários que sejam possíveis de agendamento para comparar com os resultados obtidos, porém acredito que eu seja com algum erro de lógica, pois a função mysqli_fetch_array não retorna todos os valores e inicia uma nova busca quando cai na condição do if() que coloquei. Exemplificando:

Já foram agendados os horários das 18h00, 19h00 e 20h00 para o dia 28/05/2018 na quadra cujo a id = 1.

Com o código abaixo, ele me retorna 3 colunas inteiras com os arrays especificados, sendo que na primeira coluna só aparece como indisponível o horário das 18h00, na segunda coluna apenas 19h00 e na terceira coluna apenas 20h00 como indisponível.

Alguma ideia para ajustar e me trazer apenas uma coluna com os três horários indisponíveis? Muito obrigado desde já

```
                   $consulta_sql= "SELECT hora_agendada FROM tabela_agendamentos WHERE data='$data_escolhida_pelo_usuario' AND id_quadra_escolhida_pelo_usuario='1'";
                   $query   = mysqli_query($infos_conexao, $consulta_sql)

                    while ($dados_do_mysql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                       foreach ( array("9:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00") as $hora_array ) {
                            if($hora_array == $dados_do_mysql['hora']){
                                $hora_array ='Horário Indisponível';
                              }
                              echo $hora_array;
                          }

                     }
```

Comment: Está meio confuso, pode adicionar uma imagem de como está a saída e como deveria sair

Comment: Imagem adicionada com a saída de 3 buscas que comentei. Deveria apenas aparecer uma delas com os horários registrados no banco aparecendo como "Indisponíveis". Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro, isso ocorre por causa dos dois loops, um dentro do outro, use a função `in_array` como na resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução que encontrei pro seu problema é a seguinte:

Você tem o `array()` de horas que já foram escolhidas como resposta da query através do `mysqli_fetch_array()`, que no exemplo atribuí como `$horas_cadastradas`, no seu caso seria:

```
$horas_cadastradas = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Você tem a matriz de horas totais, que no exemplo atribuí como `$horas_totais`.

Usando o laço `foreach()` no array `$horas_totais` e usando a função `in_array()` para verificar se a hora existe no array `$horas_cadastradas`:

```
$horas_cadastradas = array("18:00","19:00","20:00");
$horas_totais = array("9:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00");
foreach ($horas_totais as $hora) {
    if(in_array($hora,$horas_cadastradas)){
        echo '"Horário Indisponível"<br>';
    }else{
        echo $hora."<br>";
    }
}
```

Conseguimos chegar ao resultado de:

```
9:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
"Horário Indisponível"
"Horário Indisponível"
"Horário Indisponível"
21:00
22:00
23:00
```

> **♦** [Referencia da função in_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)

`while` de criação do `array()`:

```
while ($dados_do_mysql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $horas_cadastradas[]=$dados_do_mysql['hora'];
}
```

Comment: @wess_Smith, Obrigado pela resposta, porém não obtive sucesso. Colocando o código tal qual vc passou deu certo, o problema é quando troco a variável que vc atribuiu como $horas_cadastradas = array("18:00","19:00","20:00"); a receber a consulta do banco: $horas_cadastradas = mysqli_fetch_array($query). A saída é um erro de sintaxe onde ele pede um array e estamos passando uma string. Tentei fazer a conversão, porém a saída volta para o meu problema inicial.

Comment: então faz um while e cria o array dentro dele

Comment: Boa! funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado @Wess_Smith

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar